# Data not rendering using Ajax and the rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am using the rest frame in my django app in order to access some data.

For some reason, I do not manage to access it. I have no error message but the data is not showing up.

my views are.

```
class TeamChartData(APIView):
    queryset = MyUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyUserSerializer, #ProjectSerializer
    permission_classes = []
    http_method_names = ['get',]


    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return self.serializer_class

def get(self, request, format=None, *args, **kwargs):
        cohesiveness_score = get_team_cohesivenss_score(self)         
        data = {
        "cohesiveness_score":cohesiveness_score[0],
    }
    return Response(data)
```

my Html :

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block body %}
<div class="container paddingtop80 marginbottom30">
<div class="row">
{% if project.has_member_responses %}
  <div class="col-8">
    <div class="jumbotron greenback">
      <h4>Welcome to the Project test "{{  project.name }}" Detail page</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="jumbotron greenback">
      <div class="inner-score">
        <h6>Team Score</h6>
        <h4>{{cohesiveness_score}}</h4>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

    {% else %}
      <div class="col">
        <div class="jumbotron greenback">
          <h4>Welcome to the Project "{{  project.name }}" Detail page</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    {%endif%}
</div>

<!-- case 1 = if there is not team created or linked -->
    {% if project.team_id == None  %}
      {% include "projectdetailtemp/noteamcreated.html" %}<
<!-- case 2 = if there is a team created but no team members -->
    {% elif project.team_id and project.team_id.members.count == 0 %}
      {% include "projectdetailtemp/teamnomember.html" %}<
<!-- any other situation -->
    {% else %}
      {% include "projectdetailtemp/other.html" %}
    {% endif %}


{% if project.has_member_responses %}
  {% include "survey/team_dashboard.html" %}
{% else %}

  <div class="jumbotron redback">
      We are still waiting for all members to answer the team questionnaire
  </div>

{% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock%}


<script>
var endpoint = 'api/chart/data2'
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: endpoint,
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data)
    cohesiveness_score = data.cohesiveness_score
  }
  })
  </script>
```

when I go to my endpoint I can see the data that I am trying to access to the problem does not come from the view.py I guess.. 
The data I am trying to access is :{{cohesiveness_score}}
Could someone help me ?

edited:
the view in question :

```
def TeamSelect(request):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    if request.method == "POST":
        select_form = EditSelectTeam(request.user, request.POST)
        if select_form.is_valid():
            data = select_form.cleaned_data['team_choice']
            obj2 = Project.objects.filter(project_hr_admin=request.user)
            obj3 = obj2.latest('id')
            if obj3.team_id == None:
                obj3.team_id = data
                obj3.save()
                obj4 = obj3.team_id
                obj5 = obj4.members.all()

                for i in obj5:
                    current_site = get_current_site(request)
                    message = render_to_string('acc_join_email.html', {
                        'user': i.first_name,
                        'domain':current_site.domain,
                        })
                    mail_subject = 'You have been invited to SoftScores.com please LogIn to get access to the app'
                    to_email = i.email
                    email = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[to_email])
                    email.send()
                messages.success(request, 'test')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('website:ProjectDetails', kwargs={'pk':obj3.id}))
            else:
                print('this project has already a team')
        else:
            print('Non Valid form')

    else:
        select_form = EditSelectTeam(request.user)
    return render(request,'link_project.html',
                            {'select_form':select_form })
```

the url :

```
url(r'^project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/linkteam2/$', views.TeamSelect, name='team_select'),
```

the link :

```
<a href="{% url 'website:team_select' pk1=project.id %}" class="btn btn-secondary" role="button"><span class="fa fa-link"></span>   Link an existing team</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default rendering class of Views in Django rest is `JSONRenderer`. You need to define your rendering class to HTML and template name. After this, yiur data will be rendered in HTML.

```
from rest_framework.renderers import TemplateHTMLRenderer

class TeamChartData(APIView):
    queryset = MyUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyUserSerializer, #ProjectSerializer
    permission_classes = []
    http_method_names = ['get',]
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'template_name.html'
```

Comment: I get NameError: name 'TemplateHTMLRenderer' is not defined, I tried from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer with no success

Comment: Bro you first need to import this. 
`from rest_framework.renderers import TemplateHTMLRenderer`

Comment: yes yes sorry I just tried it but now I get :django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'team_select' with keyword arguments '{'pk1': ''}' not found.
1 pattern(s) tried: ['website/project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/linkteam2/$']

Comment: Their is some issue with your urls. You have not defined url which you are accessing.

Comment: `project.id` in your case is empty (`{'pk1': ''}`) that is why it is not matching url pattern.

Comment: how can I fix it please ? because project.id should exit I am on my project detail page..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162546/discussion-between-ben2pop-and-m-hassan).

Comment: The view in which you are rendering your template, you would be passing some data. You should pass project to it.

Comment: the view I am in pK1 is defined .. is it a way to specify it template_name = 'project_details.html' maybe ?

Comment: The data you are passing to `render` function in your view should have a key `project` which is an object. You also pass a template on which data should be rendered. You can pass any template you want.